# Use CSS to move button content to top right of bootstrap tab

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/gEPJT/226/) is a jsfiddle of some tabs I have in bootstrap that I have added an 'x' button to.  I already have all my js working fine to actually close tabs with the button.. I'm a little weak with css though still.  How can I move the button 'x' to the top right of the tab?? Below is my code(using default bootstrap css for all of this)

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-justified">
      <li id="shellstab" class="active"><a role="tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#shells" aria-expanded="true">Shell<button class="close closeTab" type="button" >&times;</button></a>
    <li id="wikitab"><a role="tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#wiki" aria-expanded="true">Wiki<button class="close closeTab" type="button">&times;</button></a>
    <li id="querytab"><a role="tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#query" aria-expanded="true">Query<button class="close closeTab" type="button">&times;</button></a>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend to create a external css file.

But... put this in the "X" Button

```
style="position: absolute; top:0; right:0;"
```

[Look at this jsFiddle:](http://jsfiddle.net/Equero/82p7ebrx/)

Comment: That was it. For some reason I was using position relative based on an example I found.  Thanks for the help. I'm going to go look up what all that does anyways.  I would have thought the numbers were down from top and right...but apparently that isn't it.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: And I paid attention to your fiddle this time and saw it can go by percent.  Thanks again!